# Does Robinhood still support its API?

Tags: python, python-requests

Does Robinhood still support its API. I keep getting a login failed error. Here's what I tried:

import requests

```
def login():
   u = "myusername"
   p = "mypassword"
   url = "https://api.robinhood.com/api-token-auth/"   
   data = {"username": u, "password": p}
   r = requests.post(url, json=data)
   return r.text

print login()
```

I also unsuccessfully tried most of the "Python API Wrappers" on Github.

Comment: I am most of the time very confused by ppl asking helpdesk questions on SO. Granted I do not know robinhood.com ... but .. don't they provide help to their services?

Comment: I wish they did

Comment: Did you try the curl example in the [unofficial docs](https://github.com/sanko/Robinhood/blob/master/Authentication.md#logging-in)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
import requests

def login():
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    header = {"Accept": "application/json"}
    data = {"client_id": "c82SH0WZOsabOXGP2sxqcj34FxkvfnWRZBKlBjFS",
            "expires_in": 86400,
            "grant_type": "password",
            "password": "pword",
            "scope": "internal",
            "username": "uname"}

    url = "https://api.robinhood.com/oauth2/token/"
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
    return r.text

print(login())
```

Comment: Robinhood says: `{"detail":"This version of Robinhood is no longer supported. Please update your app or use Robinhood for Web to log in to your account."}`. There are lots of outdated examples online that used to work, and no official documentation! This one has gone by the wayside apparently. If I find the current version I'll post it here

Comment: Got to add `device_token` to the payload

Comment: what the client_id value reflect or indicate here?